# Own lines in Chrome prediction (Omnibox addressbar autocomplete)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to get predictions from my intranet-wiki into chrome.

In this example I type "teame" and get some results for "teamevent"

[image: intranet-results-in-chrome-prediction]

How could I integrate our cooperate intranet/wiki there?

Comment: The only API is https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox

Comment: Looking for the absolute same thing (in my case, I want to register multiple company internal tools to be searched in any omnibox search, even *without* having to specifically prefix my search with a keyword) - @guettli can you let me know whether you've found a solution? :)

Comment: @alex_jwb90 thank you for creating a bounty. Up to now, I could not find a solution. AFAIK the omnibox API does not provide this up to now.